# Bloquear fechas futuras en un input date

Tags: javascript, php

¿Alguien me podría decir cómo bloquear fechas futuras en un `<input type="date">`?

Lo que necesito es que solo me permita seleccionar fechas pasadas y el día actual, pero no permita seleccionar fechas futuras (a partir del día actual).

En pocas palabras, que solo permita seleccionar desde el día actual hacia atrás.

```html
<input type='date' name='fecha' />
```

Comment: Me percaté que usaste la etiqueta "php" en tu pregunta, por lo que he editado mi respuesta con diferentes soluciones que puedes usar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que debes usar en este caso, es javascript.

Para este proceso, asignaremos el valor al atributo `max` del `input` directamente. A este atributo le asignaremos la fecha. En este caso, la fecha máxima será la de hoy.

Con el `Date()` estamos generando la fecha actual.

Posteriormente usamos [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), que convierte la fecha a un formato ISO (*`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`*). Pero el formato siempre es el mismo, el cual se separa por una "T" intermedia.

Acto seguido, queremos seleccionar la fecha de este formato (*`YYYY-MM-DD`*), por lo que hacemos uso de `split()` y separamos por dicha letra "T".

Por último, seleccionados la primera posición que nos ha dejado el `split()`, simplemente añadiendo `[0]`.

```js
datePickerId.max = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
```

```html
<input type="date" id="datePickerId" />
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias @excorpion ...

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta y votarla por favor. Si necesitas explicación del proceso, la puedo añadir también.

Answer (score 3):

Dado que tienes la etiqueta <kbd>php</kbd> en tu pregunta, tienes tres formas de conseguir hacer lo que deseas:

- El servidor, usando PHP.
- En el cliente, usando Javavascript:

  - Solo ese `<input>`.
  - Cualquier `<input>`.

En todos los casos **el objetivo es cambiar el atributo el atributo [`max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/max) de la etiqueta `<input>`** con la fecha en formato ISO (aaaa-mm-dd) para que no permita seleccionar una fecha posterior.

### En el servidor, usando PHP

Bastaría con cambiar el código por:

```
<input type="date" name="fecha" max="<?= date("Y-m-d") ?>" />
```

De manera que el cliente recibirá el HTML con el atributo obtenido con la función [`date()`](https://php.net/es/date).

Además, si tienes varios `<input type="date">` en los que deseas aplicar esta limitación, basta con agregar el código con el atributo solo en aquellos en los que necesites aplicar la limitación de fecha.

### En el cliente, usando Javascript

Al hacer el trabajo en el lado del cliente deberemos usar la función [`Date.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) para obtener la fecha y hora en formato ISO.

Tras eso podremos quedarnos con los 10 primeros caracteres (aaaa-mm-dd) o bien dividir el resultado por el separador de fecha y hora, la `T`, y quedarnos solo con la parte de la fecha. Yo me he decantado por el primer caso, por lo que el código será vulnerable al efecto 10.000 dentro de 7.979 años :)

```js
/* Esperamos a la carga del DOM */
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (evento) => {
    /* Obtenemos la fecha de hoy en formato ISO */
    const hoy_fecha = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
    /* Buscamos la etiqueta, ya sea por ID (que no tiene) o por su selector */
    document.querySelector("input[name='fecha']").max = hoy_fecha;
});
```

```html
<input type='date' name='fecha' />
```

He modificado la solución inicial para que ésta espere al evento de generación del DOM para que el código javascript sea independiente de su localización.

### En el cliente, usando Javascript, mejorado

¿Y si tenemos varios campos `<input type="date">` y algunos queremos que estén limitados al día de hoy y otros no?

Podríamos repetir el código una y otra vez para cada elemento que requiera ser modificado, duplicando código, o bien crear una solución genérica:

```js
/* Esperamos a la carga del DOM */
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (evento) => {
    /* Obtenemos la fecha de hoy en formato ISO */
    const hoy_fecha = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
    /* Buscamos solo las etiquetas que tengan el atributo "max" en "hoy" */
    document.querySelectorAll("input[type='date'][max='hoy']")
    .forEach(elemento => {
        /* A cada elemento encontrado le asignamos el atributo "max" */
        elemento.max = hoy_fecha;
    });
});
```

```html
<input type='date' name='fecha1' max="hoy" />
<input type='date' name='fecha2' />
<input type='date' name='fecha3' max="hoy" />
<input type='date' name='fecha4' />
```

Como puedes comprobar, solo a los `<input type="date">` que tengan el atributo `max` con el valor `hoy` se les cambiará dicho atributo por la fecha del día de hoy.

Tu trabajo se simplifica, no tendrás que preocuparte por repetir código por cada campo de fecha que quieras limitar, solo debes preocuparte de incluir el atributo `max="hoy"` para que el script haga el trabajo por ti.